# Deleting all charts in a powerpoint slide using excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

i have the below code: I am trying to delete the three charts in slide 4. The below deletes two of them and leaves one even though it is of the same type to the other two. Any ideas why this might be?

```
With PPApp.ActiveWindow
.View.GotoSlide Index:=4
For Each Chart In .View.slide.Shapes
    If Chart.Type = msoPicture Then
        Chart.Delete
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Debug your code. Go throug it by using F8 and check if it loops through all the shapes and check the values of your variables to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Instead of deleting, try `Debug.Print Chart.Type`. Maybe some of those charts/shapes got a different Type than `msoPicture `

Comment: I tried debugging but was unable to determine the cause. there is no indication as to what charts are being selected each loop.

Comment: Is there a way to check, in PPT, the type of the picture/chart?